# Using temp value for pointer in function

Tags: c, assembly, avr

I viewed the AES example from microchip. They write the following code segment:

```
bool AES_encrypt(uint8_t * plaintext, uint8_t * ciphertext, uint8_t * key)
{
    bool encrypt_ok;

    uint8_t * temp_key = key;
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++){
        AES.KEY =  *(temp_key++);
}
```

Why do they copy the pointer in a temporary variable? I verified it with Atmel studio and the dissassembler and both of this cases

```
bool AES_encrypt(uint8_t * plaintext, uint8_t * ciphertext, uint8_t * key)
{
    bool encrypt_ok;

    /* Load key into AES key memory. */
    uint8_t * temp_key = key;
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++){
        AES.KEY =  *(temp_key++);
}   

bool AES_encrypt(uint8_t * plaintext, uint8_t * ciphertext, uint8_t * key)
{
    bool encrypt_ok;

    /* Load key into AES key memory. */
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++){
        AES.KEY =  *(key++);
}
```

result in the same assembler code (-O1 option). So what is the goal for this notation?

Comment: The code could have looked differently earlier, where the original pointer perhaps was used after the loop? Perhaps the developers misunderstood how emulating pass-by-reference in C works? This isn't really anything anyone here could answer, unless this question is seen by the original developers.

Comment: The complete example is here:
https://github.com/Synapseware/xmega-intro/tree/master/avr1318-aes/code
The pointer is used after the function call. But the code works asswell if I don´t copy the pointer in temporary variables. So my first thought was, that this notation is usefull by any kind of optimization...
But it´s okay if nobody has an idea why he could use this.

Comment: I'd say it is just a minor missing cosmetic clean-up of the code. Nothing to dwell on.

Comment: I remember seeing a c++lint warning about modifying a function parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, in an optimized build there's no performance advantage or disadvantage whatsoever, any compiler worth its salt will reduce both of them to pretty much the exact same IR in the early stages of optimization.

It may just be a stylistic choice, some people find it confusing to modify the parameters directly, and they prefer to leave them as they are throughout the whole function; doubly so as this is example code, so it's meant to be easily understandable by programmers of all levels.

Extra advantages to this approach include the fact that it's easier to add code that refers to the original values (possibly debug statements) or to inspect the original value in a debugger in debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered good practice to not modify the arguments of a function call (i.e. abuse them as local variables). This is probably the reason for the use of the temporary variable `temp_key`, since the pointer is incremented here:

```
AES.KEY =  *(temp_key++);
```

This is *not* to be confused with altering the value of the pointer target (which the downvoter here probably has done). That is common practice of course.

See also the discussion here: [Using function arguments as local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753494/using-function-arguments-as-local-variables)

As you observed, this does not make any difference for the actual assembler code, so they decided to follow this paradigma, which helps keeping the overview in complex functions.